# What is the best way to implement Security in WebApi 2?

Tags: oauth, asp.net-web-api

Although Web API 2 provides a build-in Authentication implementation using OAuth, but when I read about [OAuth Bearer Tokens](http://hueniverse.com/2010/09/oauth-bearer-tokens-are-a-terrible-idea/), I get confused. Using Basic authentication is not a choice for me as we don't want to use SSL.

What do you think is the best security implementation for a publicly accessed API?

Comment: by publicly accessed do you mean, mainly you guys use the api, or do you want developers to be able to register their application with your service, and thus you also control which applications have access to your api

Comment: yes, mainly few SharePoint web parts (deployed on customer's server) & a Mobile WebApp (used by customer's employees) are going to use these API. So far, we don't want developers to be able to register their app with our service, but that could be a case in future, when partner developers may want to build apps that use our service.

Comment: Basically we use OAuth or JWT or Custom Token based authentication based on scenarious but I would like to ask for a very specific scenario which suits for almost implementations.

I need to implement an HTTP API using ASP.net 5 Web API v2 for to expose our Web application methods for third party applications or developers so they can directly call our API methods. But I need this to authenticate this API using some standard authentication methods so no one could breach into them.
A good example will be google developer api's as they provide client id and client secret for authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*What i would do now:*
First of, as Badri states, it is important to use SSL, otherwise there is no point in securing the api...
Now you can provide some login action (e.g. a post request to https://my.webapi.com/login) with all the post information.
If the person is authenticated you can respond with a "bearer token" actually it can be any token you want. A token is basically a random string. you can have numbers,letters etc in it.
These tokens are used so the user does not need to send his credentials with every request. It is important to note that this token has to expire of course (e.g. after an hour of inactivity for example).
The user now will have to send this token with every request. This will be used to authenticate the user with every subsequent request. (for as long as the token is valid of course) 
To provide a better user experience you could also send a refresh token when the user authenticates. This refresh token is also kept on the users side, and will be used to refresh the token. This way the user does not need to provide it's credentials for as long as this refresh token is valid. This can be much longer than the normal "authentication token" since it is send on very few occasions over a secure connection, thus the chance of it being intercepted is very small.
There is one more thing to take into account: Session hijacking. If someone would be able to get a hold of the token, he can, without the knowledge of the user, impersonate the user. To prevent this (somewhat) you should link these tokens to the users current ip address. If the ip address differs, he would have to login again.

As i mentioned before, you login securely with a post request, and get some tokens back. These tokens have to be send with every request the user makes. With the http protocol you can simply give the token in the the http header. Either in the Authorization part of the header or in some header of your own. (Convention dictates that your own headers start with X-, thus you can use e.g. X-My-Webapi-Auth-token)

*What i would do later:* 
This works perfectly as long as you are in control of all the applications using the api. If you want to open the api up to external developers you will need to put in more security measures since you might want to be able to e.g. block an application, make them pay after x requests, etc... 
But when you get to that point, you might want to consider setting up an OAUTH service for authentication, which is a similar story, but a bit more complex. I (or someone else) could elaborate on the measures you could take then, in case you really want it.

Comment: Hi rik, I am in a phase now where I want to open the api to external developers and allow them to register their clients. But those external applications will be deployed within intranet only. Can you suggest a best possible way to implement OAuth "Client Credential Flow" kind of authentication for the web api?

Comment: Basically you let every application register and give them their key. They will have to register what domain (or subdomain) their request will come from. Upon receiving a request, you check their key, and what it's point of origin is. (so nobody can use someone else's key)

Comment: try registering an application with a google api, this is about what they do as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use SSL, you cannot use bearer tokens, period. It is exactly same as using basic authentication over plain HTTP. The basic premise on which the bearer token is built is that there will be transport security. The post you have quoted, which is by Eran Hammer is about why message based security is better compared to bearer token + SSL. If you have a constraint in using SSL, you must not use bearer token.

Transport security (SSL) is an absolute minimum nowadays. If you cannot use it, because you cannot buy certificates, you will need to reconsider that decision. If there is any other valid reason, take a look at [Hawk Authentication](https://github.com/hueniverse/hawk) by Eran. Thinktecture IdentityModel has Hawk implementation (both as a message handler and OWIN middleware). Take a look at it [here](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/tree/master/source/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Hawk).